# trying to ge google plus one count and getting 'unable to parse json error 32700'

Tags: count, google-plus-one

I am trying to get google plus one count using this [article](https://gist.github.com/jonathanmoore/2640302)

this is my code:

```
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyAr1iwJ7rDsRx9BwS6M6MArYrNHfDtQJqk");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        var paramss = new MyStruct()
        {
            id = domain,
            source = "widget",
            nolog = true,
            userId = "@viewer",
            groupId = "@self",
        };
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var str = serializer.Serialize(paramss);
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = "method=pos.plusones.get";
        postData += "&id=p";
        postData += "&jsonrpc=2.0";
        postData += "&key=p";
        postData += "&apiVersion=v1";
        postData += "&params=" + str;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
       // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

but keep getting the same error:

```
{"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Unable to parse json","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"parseError","message":"Unable to parse json"}]}}
```

I am not trying to parse to json on my code so I don't really know where to start.
Any ideas?

Comment: What `Content-Type` are you sending, if you don't know send the following header: `Content-Type: application/json`.
Also how are you sending the `POST` body?

Comment: Using this online request tool: https://www.hurl.it returns a bad API error, which I'd expect as I used `YOUR_API_KEY` as the `key` parameter! (I also didn't bother setting a `Content-Type`)

Comment: @Rich I've updated the code above...

Comment: You're using URL encoded POST data, you should just be sending that whole JSON body just as it is

Comment: @Rich solved it thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

solved it, came across the following [article](http://johndyer.name/getting-counts-for-twitter-links-facebook-likesshares-and-google-1-plusones-in-c-or-php/) and this is what I've used:

```
 string googleApiUrl = "https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ";  

            string postData = @"[{""method"":""pos.plusones.get"",""id"":""p"",""params"":{""nolog"":true,""id"":""" + url + @""",""source"":""widget"",""userId"":""@viewer"",""groupId"":""@self""},""jsonrpc"":""2.0"",""key"":""p"",""apiVersion"":""v1""}]";

            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(googleApiUrl);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json-rpc";
            request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

            System.IO.Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
            writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            writeStream.Close();

            System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            System.IO.StreamReader readStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string jsonString = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            readStream.Close();
            responseStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<test>>(jsonString);
            var dic = json.ToDictionary(d=>d.id, d=>d.result);
            var count = Convert.ToInt32(decimal.Parse(((Dictionary<string, object>)((Dictionary<string, object>)((Dictionary<string, object>)dic["p"])["metadata"])["globalCounts"])["count"].ToString()));

            return count;
```